# Star-Rating Feature in GWT: how to implement partially-filled stars?

Tags: gwt

How would one implement a star-rating feature like this [image] in GWT?  Does a library exist?

Main scenario: display a decimal rating as partially filled stars.

- A call to server returns a [0, 5] decimal rating/grade, say 3.4.
- UI display 3.4/5 filled stars, something looking like this [image].

By default, the best approach I can think of would be to create a number of small pre-filled images in a client bundle with a given rating resolution, say 0.5 (~ 10 images) or 0.1 (~ 50) images.  And then write the mapping logic to display the appropriate star-filled image.
Is is the most efficient way of going about it?

A *perhaps optimized* version of this approach would be to have images of one partially filled star and then the display logic would assembled the 5 stars as function of rating -- e.g., for 3.4, 3 fully filled stars, one partially filled star to 0.4 level, one empty star.

Complement scenario: enter an integer rating {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} stars.

- Display five void stars.
- When user mouse over a star, the star and all stars to the left fill up.
- When user click, integer rating is registered.

Using a similar approach as above, two-images would suffice: one with no background, one filled.

Again, is there a widget/library out there wrapping such a common web-app feature?

It does not seem difficult to implement but no need to re-invent the wheel!  A good library of such a common web-app feature could have more embedded functions like managing the rating list by rating and their corresponding display, entering review panel, etc, all performance optimized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create three star images: complete, empty and half-full.
2. Create a custom widget. Use FlowPanel as a container with star images inside.
3. Create method showRating() in this widget:

(a) Clear stars if you already had them.

(b) Add complete star images for each round point.

(c) Add half-empty star image for half-point, if necessary.

(d) Add empty star images if necessary to make 5 stars in total.

It's a fairly simply widget. You don't need a library for that.